# Read specific csv files in multiple directories with R

Tags: r, directory, read.csv

I need to read specific csv files stored in multiple directories with R. Each directory contains these files (and others) which however are listed under different names but with distinct characters that make them recognisable.

Let's suppose the csv files I want to read contains the following distinct character: '1' (file 1) and '2' (file 2).

Here's the code I tried so far:

```
# This is the main directory where all your the sub-dir with files are stored
common_path = "~/my/main/directory"

# Extract the names of the sub-dir
primary_dirs = list.files(common_path) 

# Create empty list of lists
data_lst = rep(list(list()), length(primary_dirs)) # one list per each directory

# These are the 2 files (by code) that I need to read
names_csv = c('1', '2')

#### Nested for loop reading the csv files into the list of lists
for (i in 1:length(primary_dirs)) {

    for (j in 1:length(names_csv)) {

    data_lst[[i]][j] = read.csv(paste('~/my/main/directory/', primary_dirs[i],  
                                      '/name_file', names_csv[j],  '.csv', sep = ''))

    }
}
### End of nested loop
```

The  issue here is that the code works only if the names of the files are identical within each directory. But this is not the case. Each directory has different file names but the file names contain the distinct characters '1' and '2'.

E.g. in this case my files in all directories are called 'name_file1.csv' and 'name_file2.csv'. But in my real case the names of files are something like: dir 1 -> 'name_bla_1.csv', 'name_bla_2.csv'; dir 2 -> 'name_gya_1.csv' 'name_gya_2.csv'; etc...

How can I read these 2 files from all my directories with files having different names?

Thanks

Comment: try using regex

Comment: any hint in code language? :)

Comment: What is the common element between all the files that you want to read? `name_`?

Comment: the common element is '.csv'

Comment: So you want to read all csv files?

Comment: no...just the one with 1 and 2

Comment: `files_to_read = list.files(path = common_path, pattern = ".*(1|2).*csv$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`. Then `data_lst = lapply(files_to_read, read.csv)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making things much too complicated. `list.files` can search *recursively* (within directories), can return the full file path so you don't have to worry about `paste`ing together where the file path, and can match regex `pattern`s.

```
files_to_read = list.files(
  path = common_path,        # directory to search within
  pattern = ".*(1|2).*csv$", # regex pattern, some explanation below
  recursive = TRUE,          # search subdirectories
  full.names = TRUE          # return the full path
)
data_lst = lapply(files_to_read, read.csv)  # read all the matching files
```

To learn more about regex, I'd recommend regex101.com. `.*`, `(1|2)` matches 1 or 2, and `$` matches the end of the string, so `".*(1|2).*csv$"` will match all strings that contain a 1 or 2 and end in csv.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to read in any matching filenames from any subdirectories, you could try this:

```
regular_expression <- "name_[A-z]+_"
names_csv <- c('1', '2')
names_to_read <- paste0(regular_expression, names_csv, "\\.csv", collapse = "|")
fileList <- list.files(pattern = names_to_read, path = common_path, 
                       recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)    
data_lst <- lapply(files_to_read, function(x) read.csv(x))
```

The output should be a list, where each entry is one of your csv files.

It wasn't clear to me if you wanted to maintain separation based on the directory each file was read from, so I haven't included that.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to use an anonymous function in `lapply` if you are mapping over the first argument. `lapply(files_to_read, read.csv)` works just fine. You can even pass additional arguments with `lapply`'s `...`, e.g., `lapply(files_to_read, read.csv, header = FALSE)` is equivalent to `lapply(files_to_read, function(x) read.csv(x, header = FALSE))`. Welcome to the site!